# Could ルフレ be considered a gender-neutral name?

Tags: loanwords, names, gender

In the Fire Emblem: Awakening game, the [avatar character](http://fireemblemwiki.org/wiki/Avatar_(Awakening)#Fire_Emblem:_Awakening) — that is, the main character whose name and gender you pick — has a default name. In English, the default name is Robin, because the character can be male or female. Robin is arguably a gender-neutral name in English, so it seems to be a good choice.

In the Japanese version, the default name is ルフレ (Reflet). Does this reasonably come across as "sounding" gender-neutral in the minds of Japanese players? Or do they have no such context because it's a foreign name?

Comment: Sounds gender-neutral to me. Maybe with a tiny slant towards female (just like "Robin" for me, really). I will let a Japanese person answer though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Or do they have no such context because it's a foreign name?

This. ルフレ sounds very foreign to me, a native Japanese speaker who loves games. People don't have any clue how to determine whether it's a male name or female name. (But if I have to guess, I would imagine it's possibly an European female name.)

I googled "ルフレ", and then excluded "-ファイヤーエムブレム", and "-スマブラ" (where ルフレ from FE appears as a playable character). I could find only one different [character](http://nekowiz.com/archives/40234361.html) with the same name, and I think she is not so famous.